# Woocommerce/WP shortcode replacement

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have a woocommerce site and want the search function to pull products based on product tags as well.
I found a plugin that can do that but I don't get much help from the developer.
Basically I have a shortcode for the advanced serach plugin that I need to place in the theme functions.php file.
I am a newbie and not sure where to place/replace it.
This would be the shortcode:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[aws_search_form id="YOUR_ID"]' );
```

Here is the theme's search form code:

```
<?php if ( (isset($shopkeeper_theme_options['main_header_search_bar'])) && 
($shopkeeper_theme_options['main_header_search_bar'] == "1") ) : ?>
                    <li class="search-button">
                        <a class="tools_button">
                            <span class="tools_button_icon">
                                <?php if ( 
(isset($shopkeeper_theme_options['main_header_search_bar_icon'])) && 
($shopkeeper_theme_options['main_header_search_bar_icon'] != "") ) : ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo 
esc_url($shopkeeper_theme_options['main_header_search_bar_icon']); ?>">
                                <?php else : ?>
                                <i class="spk-icon-search"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your shortcode in any file in your theme not only in functions.php,

So you can modify your search.php like these :

```
<?php if ( (isset($shopkeeper_theme_options['main_header_search_bar'])) && 
($shopkeeper_theme_options['main_header_search_bar'] == "1") ) : ?>

        <?php echo do_shortcode( '[aws_search_form id="YOUR_ID"]' ); ?> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Great, thanks. It works on desktop, mobile is the problem now. I guess the theme's responsive design is too specific. Do you think I can place this shortcode in a way in this theme's code in a way that the design does not get changed but the advanced search functionality works? Thanks

Comment: Please explain more your demande thanks .. and please mark my answer as accepted .. thank you